# Consulta MYSQL Con Join

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, join

Tengo la siguiente BBDD : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZfqM.png

Y la consulta que debo realizar es la siguiente:

**Muestre las Asignaturas y Profesores asociados al edificio que sea Banesco**

Hice esto pero tengo claro que tengo errores y me gustaría saber como solucionarlo, gracias!

```
SELECT profesor.nombre_p AS nombreProfesor, asignatura.nombre
FROM profesor, asignatura JOIN 
( salon JOIN clase ON salon.idsalon = clase.salonid  )
ON profesor.idprofesor = clase.profesorid
WHERE salon.edificio= "Banesco";
```

Answer (score 1):

No estas tan mal encaminado (creo), un par de `JOINS` más y obtienes el resultado, básicamente la tabla que te ayudará a unir todo es `clase` algo asi quiza te funcione:

```
SELECT
a.nombre_p profesor,
d.piso,
c.nombre_a asignatura
FROM profesor a 
INNER JOIN clase b on a.idprofesor = b.idprofesor
INNER JOIN asignatura c on b.idasignatura = c.idasignatura
INNER JOIN salon d on b.idsalon = d.idsalon
WHERE d.edificio = 'Banesco';
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo! Todo funciono muy bien ;)

Comment: Si la respuesta te funciono, por favor marcala como aceptada (con el cheque que aparece abajo del contador de votos). Saludos.